# Layer-list drawables side by side

Tags: android, android-xml

I cannot seem to get my layer list to work properly.

I need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:left="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient 
                android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF" 
                android:endColor="#FF000000"
                android:angle="0" />            
            <size 
                android:width="30dp"
                android:height="5dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="30dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">         
            <solid android:color="#FF000000" />
            <size 
                android:width="60dp"
                android:height="5dp" />  
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="90dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">       
            <gradient 
                android:startColor="#FF000000" 
                android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:angle="0" />
            <size
                android:width="30dp"
                android:height="5dp" />           
        </shape>    
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I want a simple line with 3 drawables each beside each other!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:left="0dp" android:right="90dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient 
                android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF" 
                android:endColor="#FF000000"
                android:angle="0" />            
            <size 
                android:width="30dp"
                android:height="5dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="30dp" android:right="30dp" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">         
            <solid android:color="#FF000333" />
            <size 
                android:width="60dp"
                android:height="5dp" />  
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="90dp" android:right="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">       
            <gradient 
                android:startColor="#FF000000" 
                android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:angle="0" />
            <size
                android:width="30dp"
                android:height="5dp" />           
        </shape>    
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I just missed android:right property, now it's working!